# Dynamically add attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have some links that is being generated like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in links"></li>
```

In the link object, there's some attributes.

```
link = {
    attributes: "required"
}
```

How can I add this attribute to the element, so It becomes like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in menu" required></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to call out that this question deserves more love, there are some cool use cases to think about with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="link in menu" {{link.attributes}}></li>
```

You may need to populate that object property in your controller, though.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This doesn't work however. The {{link.attributes}} is not being converted.

Comment: Did you work it out so that `link.attributes` is a valid property? This should work.

Comment: Not yet. I guess I need to do something with $compile

Comment: No, just assign the values in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="link in links" required="{{link.attributes}}"></li>
```

or

```
<li ng-repeat="link in links" ng-required="{{link.attributes}}"></li>
```

If you need to play with the DOM, you have to add it by a directive during [$compile][1], but it probably makes no sense for your case.

Comment: Can you add an example on how to do this during compile? Required was a bad example from me. I need the exact attribute, which will most probably be another directive